# Ring of germs of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in $0$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, germs

First of all, I'm quite new to this theory, so it may be very dumb questions. Sorry for that.

Let $R$ be the ring of germs of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in $0$. Let $K$ be the intersection of all powers of maximal ideal. I would like to prove that $K$ is generated by all nonnegative $\varphi\in R$.

I've been told that there exists only one maximal ideal:

$$M=\{f\in R\mid f(0)=0\}\tag{1}$$

It is easy, I think, to prove it is an ideal. However, I've no clue how to prove it is maximal and it is the only maximal ideal... Next, it is said that

$$M^{k}=\left\{f\in R\,\Big\vert\, \frac{\partial^{\vert\alpha\vert}f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(0)=0,\,\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{n}:\vert\alpha\vert=0,1,\dots,k-1\right\}\tag{2}$$

How can one find that? I mean, the definition of the $k$-th power of an ideal is the ideal generated by finite sums of product of its elements. For example, $M^{2}=\langle \{f\cdot g\mid f,g\in M\}\rangle$, no? I do not understand how one can get $(2)$ with such a definition. I do understand that

$$f\in M^{k}\implies\frac{\partial^{\alpha}f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(0)=0,\,\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{n}:\vert\alpha\vert=0,1,\dots,k-1$$

since it follows from the Leibniz product rule. But I don't see how we get the other direction. I'm kind of lost here and far from the result I want to show...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your first question:

Given an ideal $I \subset R$ and the desire to proof that $I$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$, you just have to show that $R \setminus I$ contains only units. Because this shows, that any proper ideal is contained in $I$, hence $I$ is the unique maximal ideal.

In our situation, this is easy to show: If $f \notin M$, we have $f(0) \neq 0$, hence $f(x) \neq 0$ in some neighborhood of $0$ by continuity. Hence $1/f$ is well defined on this neighborhood (and by some calculus, again smooth) and this shows that $f$ is invertible in $R$.

To your second question: The fact, that any $f$, whose partial derivatives vanish up to order $k-1$, is contained in $M^k$, is precisely the [Taylor formular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the first one but not the second. If the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish up to order $k-1$, how does that prove that $f$ can be expressed as the product of $k$ elements of $M$?

Comment: Just write down, what Taylor implies in this situation: $$f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k-1} \frac{D^{\alpha}f(0)}{\alpha!}x^{\alpha} + \sum_{|\beta| =k} R_{\beta}(x) x^{\beta}$$ with some smooth $R_\beta$'s. The first summand vanishes, the second summand is contained in $M^k$, since $x^\beta \in M^k$.

Comment: Ooh thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f \in R$ with $f(0) \neq 0$ then $f$ is invertible in $R$ (as $\frac{1}{f} \in R$). If an ideal $I$ of $R$ contains a function $f$ with $f(0) \neq 0$ then it contains $\frac{1}{f} \cdot f = 1$ and so we must have $I = R$. This shows that $M$ is maximal and that any proper ideal of $R$ is contained in $M$ so $M$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$.

For the interesting direction regarding $M^k$, you need to show [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma). Using Hadamard's lemma, any smooth germ can be written as $f(x) = f(0) + \sum_{i=1}^n x^i g_i(x)$ where $g_i$ are smooth. If $f(0) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(0) = 0$ then using Leibniz rule you can check that $g_i(0) = 0$ and so $f \in M^2$. By induction, you can similarly show the characterization of $M^k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very clear.

Comment: I've trouble showing the induction. We have $$\frac{\partial^{\alpha}f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(0)=0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{\vert\beta\vert\le\vert\alpha\vert}{\alpha \choose \beta}\frac{\partial^{\beta}x^{i}}{\partial x^{\beta}}(0)\frac{\partial^{\alpha-\beta}g_{i}}{\partial x^{\alpha-\beta}}(0)$$ and $$\frac{\partial^{\beta}x^{i}}{\partial x^{\beta}}(0)=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if }\beta\neq (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)\\ 1 &\text{else }\end{cases}$$ so that we can rewrite $$0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i}\frac{\partial^{\alpha-\hat{\beta}_{i}}g_{i}}{\partial x^{\alpha-\hat{\beta}_{i}}}(0)$$ How can I conclude?

Comment: You can show by induction that if $\partial^{\alpha}(f)(0) = 0$ for all $|\alpha| \leq k - 1$ then one can write $f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} x^{\alpha} g_{\alpha}(x)$ for smooth $g_{\alpha}$ (the case $k = 1$ is Hadamard's lemma). Then, if in addition $\partial^{\alpha}(f)(0) = 0$ for all $|\alpha| = k$ then Leibniz rule shows that $\partial^{\alpha}(f)(0) = g_{\alpha}(0) = 0$.

Comment: I managed to get something with my first approach but it was quite messy in terms of notations. I'll try what you suggest.